# How to pass the table name in parameter in cassandra python

Tags: python, cassandra

I want to use a variable for the name of my table in Cassandra query.

It's possible to do this :

```
self.session.execute(
            """
            INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2)
            VALUES (%s, %s)
            """,
            ("1", "2")
        )
```

But, for example, I would like to do something like this

```
self.session.execute(
            """
            INSERT INTO %s (col1, col2)
            VALUES (%s, %s)
            """,
            ("table_name","1", "2")
        )
```

It's look the wrong way ...

And sure I want keep safety about sql injection

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use prepared queries instead of that approach - when you use `%s` placeholder, then the query is not prepared the Cassandra gets an additional overhead from parsing your query every time. It's better to avoid this if you use something like this - define a map that will hold prepared queries, and in the code use the function that will prepare query that isn't in this cache. The code will look as following (not tested):

```
queries = {}
def get_query(session, stmt):
    global queries
    query = queries.get(stmt)
    if query is None:
       query = session.prepare(stmt)
       queries[stmt]=query
    return query
```

and then in the code:

```
 stmt = "select  * from %s.%s where id =?".format(ks, table)
 query = get_query(stmt)
 session.execute(query, [params])
```

See [documentation](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#id2) for more details.

Comment: It's okay for my case, but are you sure about the safety against injection?
Especially this line : 
   stmt = "select  * from %s.%s where id =?".format(ks, table)

Comment: No, not sure - that's just an example :-)