# How to parametrize the table name using Cassandra's Python driver?

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-python-driver

I have an instance method that is used to construct a Cassandra query, and I'm looking for a way to more safely parametrize the table name in a query without using string formatting.

For example,

```
def some_method(self, table_name):
    statement = f"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {self.table_name}"
    results = self.cassandra.session.execute(query=statement)
    ...
```

I don't believe `SimpleStatement` or a `PreparedStatement` can be used to bind a table name.

Comment: If no safe methods can be found (glancing at the source it does appear that the bound values are to columns), perhaps querying for a list of table names that already exist and check that `self.table_name` is found in any of them, which should _hopefully_ be safe enough (subject to table names not named in funny ways).

Comment: Did you check this? [How to pass the table name in parameter in cassandra python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292761/how-to-pass-the-table-name-in-parameter-in-cassandra-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass the table name in parameter in cassandra python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292761/how-to-pass-the-table-name-in-parameter-in-cassandra-python)

Comment: I’m specifically looking for a safe way to do this without using string formatting.

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to do this that's both safe and satisfies linters like flake8 and bandit warning about potential SQL injections due to the string formatting, even though the variable value is never coming from user/external input at all (ex. from a dict mapping)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [DataStax's Python Driver for Cassandra (as of v3.28)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.28/), there is no way to parametrize or bind the table name using [Session.execute / Session.execute_async](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.28/api/cassandra/cluster/#cassandra.cluster.Session.execute), because it only expects the column values to be in the `parameters` argument, and the table name to be hardcoded in the `statement` string. You'll have to resort to string formatting, which then makes your linters complain about possible SQL injections (which you then have to silence with `# noqa` and such).

I managed to work around this by using `cassandra.cqlengine.models` instead which is still part of the same Python driver package: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.28/api/cassandra/cqlengine/models/.

You can dynamically create the model for your table during runtime (during which you can pass the table names from somewhere), and then use that model to perform the queries.

First, define an **abstract** model:

```
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model
from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table

class MyAbstractModel(Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    __keyspace__ = "your_keyspace"

    # The table name will be defined during runtime
    # __table_name__ = ...

    id = columns.Integer(primary_key=True)
    first_name = columns.Text()
    last_name = columns.Text()
```

Then on runtime, create a **concrete** model:

```
def get_table_name() -> str:
    # Return some table name based on some app-specific logic.
    return "Person"

table_name = get_table_name()
table_attrs = {"__table_name__": table_name}
person_model = type(
    table_name,
    (MyAbstractModel,),
    table_attrs,
)

# Not shown here is setting-up the connection to the cluster
# and setting-up a session, as that's not part of the question.
# Assume an active session is already available.
sync_table(model=person_model)
```

The `type` call is Python's built-in [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function for creating a type, in this case a concrete `Person` class based on `cassandra.cqlengine.models.Model`. The arguments to `type` in order are:

- The name of the class (`table_name`)
- The base classes (`(MyAbstractModel,)`)
- The additional class attributes of your model (`table_attrs`), which in this case should be `__table_name__` (see https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.28/api/cassandra/cqlengine/models/)

If your code runs successfully, you'll see that the table is created:

```
cqlsh> DESC TABLE your_keyspace.person;

CREATE TABLE your_keyspace.person (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name text,
    last_name text
) WITH ...

cqlsh> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_keyspace.person;

 count
-------
     0
```

Once you've got your table, you can now use that to make your queries *as a replacement to using* `session.execute`. Depending on how many tables you'll need to create, you'll probably need a mapping of the table names to their models:

```
all_models = {
    "person": person_model,
    "food": food_model,
    "drink": drink_model,
    ...
}
```

Copying the example from the question where the table name is a parameter of `some_method`:

```
def some_method(self, table_name):
    model = all_models.get(table_name)
    if not model:
      raise InvalidTableNameException

    row = model(id=1234, first_name="Foo", last_name="Bar")
    row.save()
```

Since the models are dynamically created, just make sure that

- It is *still* a valid Python class name
- It is *still* a valid Cassandra table name
- The `__table_name__` and the `type` name are consistent

Read the documentation on [Making Queries](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.28/cqlengine/queryset/) with models.